# Overlay Text to an image in the Compositor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, image, text-object

is there a way to overlay a text over an image in the compositor? I usually add my website URL to final images o post on the web, and everytime i need to open the final image in gimp to overlay text. See an example here:
[image]
[Overlayed text in the lower right corner]

I already tried the stamp output under the render settings, but there is no way to choose the font type and/or the position of the text. Both should be possible.
The only useable method i got by now is to create a text as image with alpha in Gimp and then overlay it. Is there a better method?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Create a layer that contains the text object in a different render layer, and composite it over the rendered image with Alpha Over.

Comment: Hi cetagon, this is not what i meant. I need a solution for a Compositor NODE, not a text object of 3D space.I don't want to render out something over and over again that is already there- It should be similar to this thread, that unfortunately remained unanswered as well:                                                                              https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?392789-Blender-Cycles-Improvement-Idea-Text-Texture-Node

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding cetagon. I thought it was clear that the phrase "overlay a text over an image" explained that i am searching for a way to use a text from a text editor, not the 3D Text object. Anyway, is there a chance to do so?The Render layer solution is the same as overlaying a text using gimp or photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old but got no answer and I faced a similar issue so here is a workaround.

The idea is to use the image of a text and overlay it.
[image: watermark]

But if you just try to alpha over the image, you can't place it precisely in the corners. You first need to 'wrap' the watermark with a transparent frame of the size of the scene.

[image]

This way you can use the Translate node with the 'relative' option and then you can play with size, offset and transparency. Here is the node setup for the final effect :

[image: node setup]

The only drawback is that the X and y sizes of the watermark have to be entered manually. But if you need to do it just once, it's ok.

Comment: I can add one more drawback to adding text as image to your compositor and then rescaling it - You lose ton of quality of the original text when you're rescaling it. I'm looking for a different method without having to get my final render through PS.